# Question on SQS and S3 is it possible to wire SQS to publish straight to a S3 message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I am guessing the answer would be a big No. But is there a way to publish SQS messages straight to an S3 Bucket.
I know the pattern is  SQS -> Lambda ->S3. I was wondering is there a way to just publish from a SQS straight to a S3 Bucket.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your actual use-case? That is, _what_ are you wanting to achieve, as opposed to _how_ your want to achieve it? For example, where are these messages coming from? Why do you want to send them to S3? How would you like them to appear in S3? What will be using the messages once they are stored in S3?

Comment: The messages are just going to be json, that another app will be sending to the SQS Queue. All I want to know is, is it possible for SQS to store those messages to an S3 Bucket. I dont think it  is, but I have been asked to research the possiblity.

Comment: Does each message need to be stored in a separate object in Amazon S3, or can they be combined together? Instead of using Amazon SQS, you could send the data to an [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html), which can then save 'streaming' data to S3 by storing multiple messages in a single file based on a maximum file size and/or maximum duration.

Comment: Thank you, that is something I can research into

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SQS does not 'publish' messages.

Instead, apps can `SendMessage()` to an Amazon SQS queue, and then apps can request messages by calling `ReceiveMessage()`. Once they have finished processing the message, they call `DeleteMessage()`.

Comment: Yup so in this case, I would need a application Lambda in this case to be triggered to recieve the messages, and then store them on the S3 Bucket.